# When can the problem actually be fixed by catching an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

Here's the thing. There's something I don't quite understand about exceptions, and to me they seem like a construct that *almost* works, but can't be used cleanly.

I have a simple question. When has catching an exception been a useful or necessary component of solving the root cause of the problem? I.e. when have you been able to write code that fixes a problem signaled through an exception? I am looking for factual data, or experience you have had.

Here's what I mean. A normal program does work. If some piece of work can't be completed for reason X, the function responsible for doing the work throws an exception. But who *catches* the exception? As I see it, there are three reasons you might want to catch an exception:

1. You catch it because you want to change its type and rethrow it. (This happens when you translate mechanical exception, such as `std::out_of_range`, to business exceptions, such as `could_not_complete_transaction`)
2. You catch it because you want to log it, or let the user know about the problem, before aborting.
3. You catch it because you actually know how to solve the problem.

It is point 3 that I'm skeptical about. I have never actually caught an exception knowing what to do to solve it. When you get a `std::out_of_memory`, what are you supposed to do with it? It's not like you can *barter the operating system* to get more memory. That's just not something you can fix. And it's not just `std::out_of_memory`, there are also business class exceptions that suffer from this. Think about a potential `connection_error` exception: what can you do to fix this except wait and retry later and hope it fixes itself?

Now, to be fair, I do know of one case in which code does catch an exception and tries to fix the problem. I know that there are certain Win32 SEH handlers that catch a Stack Overflow exception and try to fix the problem by enlarging the size of the thread stack if it's possible. However, this works because SEH has try-resume semantics, which C++ exceptions don't have (you can't resume at the point the exception occurred).

*The main part of the question is over.* However, there's also another problem I have with exceptions that, to me, seems exactly the reason why you don't have catch clauses that fix the problem: the code that catches the exception necessarily has to be coupled with the code that throws it. Because, in order to fix the problem, it must have *domain specific* knowledge about what the problem cause is. But when some library documents that "if this function fails, an `internal_error` exception will be thrown", how am I supposed to be able to fix the problem when I don't know how the library works internally?

PS: Please note that this is not a "exceptions vs. error codes" kind of question; I am well aware that error codes suck as an error handling mechanism. They actually suffer from the same problem I have explained for exceptions.

Comment: Your PS indicates that this question actually has pretty much nothing to do with exceptions specifically. "How do you recover from an error" is a fundamentally hard problem that depends on the specifics of the error in question. Exceptions are one mechanism for doing this with their own upsides and downsides compared to other mechanisms, but as you've identified the question of "okay, I've identified the problem, but now what?" remains.

Comment: Congratulations! You've just discovered why lots of newer languages (Rust, Scala, etc.) are strongly discouraging exceptions. Take a look at the way Rust does it. There's two types of things that can go wrong: panics and results. Panics crash the current thread and are basically impossible to catch (things like out-of-memory, in your example). Results return a special value that you're absolutely, positively required to deal with or explicitly acknowledge that you're passing on (something like, say, "the element was not found in the list").

Comment: For the record, when a lot of people hear `Option` or `Result`, they think of C-style error codes. C-style error codes are awful because it's so easy to ignore them, so don't conflate that with modern, type-checked "results as error values" approaches.

Comment: I guess your imagination (or, lack thereof) might be biased. A very simple case is you want to open a file that doesn't exist: Of course that might throw an exception, and of course you can catch this and fix it by asking the user for another file name. The fact that many libraries in fact do not exactly favor the use of exceptions is that they tend to bloat the compiled code by a large amount, even on current compilers.

Comment: _"I am well aware that error codes suck as an error handling mechanism"_ Really? Unfortunately the perfect error handling strategy does not exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you equate "solve the problem" with "make the program keep going correctly". That is the *wrong* way to think of exceptions, or error handling in general.

Error handling code of any kind should not be something that is *internally fixable* by the program. That is, error handling logic (like catching exceptions) should not be entered because of *programming* mistakes.

If the user gives you a non-existent filename, that's not a programming mistake; that's a user-error. You cannot "fix" that without going back to the user and getting an existing file. But exceptions do allow you to undo what you were trying to do, restore the program to a valid state, and then communicate what happened to the user.

An `invalid_connection` is similarly not a programming mistake. Unlike the above, it's not necessarily a user error either. It's something that's expected to be able to happen, and different programs will handle it in different ways. Some will want to try again. Others will want to halt and let the user know.

The point is, because there is no one means to handle this condition, it cannot be done by the library. The error must be given to the caller of the library to figure out what to do.

If you have a function that parses integers, and you are given text that doesn't conform to an integer, it's not *that* function's job to figure out what to do next. The caller needs to be notified that the string they provided is malformed and that something ought to be done.

The caller needs to handle the error.

You don't abort most programs because a file that was supposed to contain integers didn't contain integers. But your parsing function does need to communicate this fact to the caller, and the caller does need to deal with that possibility.

That's what "catching exceptions" is for.

Now, unexpected environmental conditions like OOM are a different story. This is not usually external code's fault, but it's also not usually a programming error. And if it *is* a programming error (ie: memory leak), it's not one you can deal with in most cases. [P0709](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0709r4.pdf) has an entire section on the ability (or lack thereof) of programs to be able to generally respond to OOM. The result is that, even when programs are coded defensively against OOM exceptions, they're usually *still broken* when they run out of memory.

Especially when dealing with OS's that don't commit pages to memory until you actually use them.

Comment: So you are suggesting that actually *error handling* isn't for handling errors at all, but it is for *dealing with conditions that require callee-caller cooperation*?

Comment: @super: That what "error handling" means: dealing with an inability to complete a task which was detected in one location, but it must be handled in some way at another location in code. If the code which detected the error could handle it transparently, it wouldn't be an *error* to anybody outside of that code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take,

There are more reasons to catch exceptions, for example, if it is a critical application, such as ones found in power substations etc. and an exception is caught to which there is no known system recovery or solution, you may want to have a controlled shutdown, protect certain modules, protect connected embedded systems etc. instead of just letting the system crash on its own. The latter could be disastrous...

> I.e. when have you been able to write code that fixes a problem signaled through an exception?
> When you get a std::out_of_memory, what are you supposed to do with it? It's not like you can barter the operating system to get more memory.

Actually I feel like that was my primary coding style for a while. An example: a system I worked on did not have a huge amount of memory and the system was dedicated, so, it was only my app and nothing else. Whenever I had an out_of_memory type of exception, I'd just kill the older process and open the one with the higher priority. Of course I'd wait for the kill to happen in a controlled fashion.

> Think about a potential connection_error exception: what can you do to fix this except wait and retry later and hope it fixes itself?

I'd try to connect through another medium such as bluetooth, fiber, bus etc. Normally of course there would be a primary medium of contact, and the others wouldn't be called unless there is an exception.

> But when some library documents that "if this function fails, an internal_error exception will be thrown", how am I supposed to be able to fix the problem when I don't know how the library works internally?

Most often an exception in a dedicated library has different consequences in your system than its own. You may not need to read the library and its internal workings to fix the problem. You just need to study its effect on your software and handle that situation. That's probably the easiest solution. And that is a lot easier to do if the library raises a known exception instead of just crashing or giving gibberish answers.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing that came to mind was socket connections.

- You try and connect to Server A and the program finds that it can't do that
- Try connecting to Server B

The other examples regarding user input are equally as valid if not more so.

I admit that seeing something along the lines of

```
try
{
    connectToServerA();
}
catch(cantConnectToServer)
{
    connectToServerB();
}
```

would look like a bit of a weird pattern to see in real world code. It might make sense if the function takes an address and we iterate through a list of potential addresses.

Broadly speaking I agree with you often all you want to do is log the error and terminate - but some systems, which have to be robust and "always on" shouldn't just terminate if they encounter a problem.

Webservers are one obvious example. You don't just terminate because one users connection faulters, because that would drop the session for all the other connected users. There might be parts of code where raising an exception is the simplest way to deal with such a failure however.